# Liquidsoap Replay-Gain lowers bass sound-level

Tags: audio, audio-streaming, liquidsoap

I noticed that when using Replay-Gain in liquidsoap in order for all the tracks to be played at roughly the same volume that it adjusts the actual volume levels of the track itself and the bass becomes very flat.

I've been searching for some function (or such) to internally correct this within my liquidsoap script but have been unable to find anything alike.

Does such a function/method even exist within the liquidsoap scripting language or will I end up just having to turn up my subwoofer to achieve this?

To clarify: the bass is not completely gone, its just noticeable lower and sounds more flat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After even more days of searching I managed to find the `ladspa.*` plugins.

Please note that you will need to install certain dependencies in order to get all of them to work, for me these consisted of:

- swh-plugins
- caps

I only can confirm this for Debian, although I suspect other Linux systems (i.e. Ubuntu) will be able to use the same packages.